# What is the use of getDrawingCache() method

Tags: android

I dont know how to use `getDrawingCache()` method.please give me any example.Please explain me the method,its use and advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check setting Wallpaper SDK example

```
android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app\SetWallpaperActivity.java
```

It should be useful. For more info check:

[getDrawingCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't seem to be explicitly mentioned in the Android Dev Guide, however from looking at the reference for [View.buildDrawingCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#buildDrawingCache(boolean)), it seems to me that is used to build a bitmap representation of a `View` which is presumably used to speed-up drawing by just blitting the cached bitmap rather than drawing the (potentially complicated) View manually each time.

<strike>Could be wrong though.</strike>

Edit: many thanks Lior for the confirmation.

Comment: You're not wrong. This is correct.